# An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

We are using Azure function timer trigger.

Here is the flow of task. I am getting some data, creates a file of that data and upload it to AWS and then send the notification to specific persons to inform regarding file.

I am facing an issue that says "An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method" and when we face this issue, notification is not being sent to recipients.Though file has been created properly and uploaded to AWS everytime.

Here is the code I am using

```
public async Task ProcessData()
        {
            try
            {
                // Get data
                var data = await _process1.GetData();
                if (data != null && data.Count > 0)
                {
                    var id = 100;
                    var fileDisplayName = "file1";

                    // Process file for data
                    await _files.CreateAndUploadFileToAWS(data, id, fileDisplayName);

                    // Send Notification
                    await _notification.SendNotification(id, data.count, fileDisplayName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Here is the send mail function

```
public async Task SendNotification(int id, int noOfRecords, string displayName)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get recipients for mail
                var recipients= await _person.GetRecipients(id);
        
                // Send notification
                var subject = "Email Notification";
                var message = "message";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) && recipients.Count > 0)
                    await _mails.SendEmail(recipients, subject, message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Note: We face this issue frequently but not all the time, Some time it sends notification and sometimes it shows error.

Please help me with this.

Thank You

Comment: Don't do this  `throw new Exception(e.Message);` - you have just lost your stack trace, and its exactly what we (and you) need

Comment: ^^ Just `throw;` or better remove the try/catch if `throw;` is all you do in the catch block.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of `CreateAndUploadFileToAWS`?

Comment: Whenever you write `catch (Exception e)` you are potentially swallowing all sorts of exceptions. Don't do it. You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle.

Comment: Apart from the lack of information and debugging, see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036795/getting-error-while-sending-bulk-email-an-asynchronous-call-is-already-in-progr

Comment: I found your feedback useful. I will try this. 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the problem occures in the `SendEmail` method.
my assumption is that the problem is that you are using `SmtpClient` which prevents executing multiple asynchronous operations at the same time.

General note regarding the exception handling.. you should probably replace the exception message throwing because you won't be able to see the stack trace which can help and investigate the issue in depth.